# Mongoose saves empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After a post request, moongoose does save the document but it is empty.

I do have the model for it and the collection exists.

index.js

```
const BlogPost = require("./models/BlogPost.js");
```

BlogPost.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model("BlogPost", BlogPostSchema);
module.exports = BlogPost;
```

create method:

```
app.post("/posts/store", (req, res) => {
    BlogPost.create(req.body, (error, blogpost) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        res.redirect("/");
    });
});
```

`req.body console.log` result

```
{ '”title”': 'aaaa', '”body”': 'bbbbbbbbbb' }
```

So, when I `console.log` `req.body` I **do** get the expected data, however `blogpost` is empty and is being saved as such. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the `require` for the `BlogPost` (of create method). You can also try using the [save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents) method.

Comment: @prasad_ I've updated the model code above if that is what you meant.

Comment: Your `console.log` shows you have extra quotes around the keys. Is this coming via a frontend? How are you encoding it as JSON?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech that's it buddy, just noticed it myself. yes you are right in the front end were weird double quotes (I copy/pasted from the tutorial directly). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create async await function for sending data to mongoDb
Like this:

```
app.post("/posts/store", async (req, res) => {
const { title, body } = req.body;
const blog = await BlogPost.create({
    title,
    body,
});

res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
          blog,
      }
   })
});
```

after than if everything ok add delete **res.status(201).json** and add **res.redirect("/");**

If you don't use Postman you can test with curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \-d '{"title": 
   "titles", "body": "bodys"}' \https://localhost:<YOUR_PORT>
```

Comment: same crap, I do get `success` but `blog` is empty. I am missing something.

Comment: Actually everything is true maybe you can check out something like
1. Are MongoDb server open
2. Are mongoose version compatible with mongodb version 
3. Are mongoose connected correctly

If thant's not work you can check out my git hub repo wich i use mongoose. https://github.com/Chain-Storage/Chain-Storage-Website-V0/

Comment: No, the problem I believe is that the keys are double quoted inside single quotes hence mongoose gets confused, but I don't know why it's using both double and single quotes for keys,